# Excel-vba: Worksheetfunction.CountIfs with vba variable

Tags: excel, vba

I do use the `WorksheetFunction.CountIfs` in Excel in two different procedures. In the first procedure I use 0.7 as criteria and I do get the correct result, in the latter procedure I use a variable equal to 0.7 and I do get the (wrong) result 0 (in version 1 and version 2, see below). Is it not possible to use a variable as criteria here? It would be useful to me as I do want to use `WorksheetFunction.CountIfs` in a for loop in which the criteria is the loop counter.

In other words: Why does this work

```
Sub countIfsConstant()
Dim rngTest As Range
Dim rngTest2 As Range
Set rngTest = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(10, 1))
Set rngTest2 = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2), ActiveSheet.Cells(10, 2))
Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rngTest, ">0.7", rngTest2, "b")
End Sub
```

But this does not

```
Sub countIfsVariable()
Dim rngTest As Range
Dim rngTest2 As Range
Dim lb As Single
Set rngTest = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(10, 1))
Set rngTest2 = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2), ActiveSheet.Cells(10, 2))
lb = 0.7
Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rngTest, ">lb", rngTest2, "b") 'version 1
Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rngTest, ">" & lb, rngTest2, "b") 'version 2
End Sub
```

Comment: version 2 works for me.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is confusing. Version 2 returns 0 to me whatever my entries in the ranges are (let's say all entries in rngTest are equal to 1 and all entries in rngTest2 are "b", then I still get 0).